# gwt-unitCache Vaadin 7

Tags: gwt, vaadin7

I have a project that, for some reason, has `src/main/webapp/VAADIN/gwt-unitCache` on my Mac, the older machine where I started the project.  When I cloned the project to a newer machine and rebuilt my project ( mvn clean package ), it did not have this gwt-unitCache.  Things seem to work fine.  On the Mac, the folder has not been updated since last year ( July 2018 ).  To be honest, I am not entirely sure my version of Vaadin ( 7.7.13 ) even needs this directory anymore.  To be honest, I was late in changing to 7.7.13, so I could have done this change last year.  Is it safe to remove?

Also, for a Vaadin 7 project, what generates it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is safe to remove the `gwt-unitCache` directory/folder.  This is generated by the GWT compiler when running a GWT application in development mode (or SDM super development mode).